# TableTools not working when SWF hosted on AWS S3

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I'm trying to use jQuery DataTables and TableTools in conjunction with my Django app, which uses Django-Storages (Boto) to manage my static files on S3. Although I can successfully point my SWF file to the SWF on S3, I've noticed that none of the COPY CSV etc buttons work (except PRINT) when using S3. However, it all works perfectly once I point to a public CDN.

I can use the CDN but am wondering if anyone knows why it doesn't work on S3. I'm guessing it may be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem with SWF on S3. I solve it stupid way by moving the swf file back to server instead of load from S3.
Hope this help.

My theory below, not tested:
I suspect it is due to the cross domain issue, as load from S3, the file path changed as well the domain name. This could happen if the Action Script did not check if crossdomain policy specified.